# Allow_url_include is there a way to allow includes from just one url

Tags: .htaccess, php

`allow_url_include` is there a way to allow includes from just one Url. maybe with Htaccess or in the PHP?

Comment: Can you give a concrete example?  I'm confused over how you could accomplish what you desire using `.htaccess` as `allow_url_include` appears to allow PHP running on one server to access a file on another web server in an `include` statement.

Comment: only type the include statement once? Just because you allow remote includes does not mean they will suddenly start popping up in your ode.

Comment: No. It's an all-or-nothing setting. Either it's on and alows anything, or it's off and allows nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. To fetch the contents of a URL, use [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php). Then, to send the result back to the waiting browser, just use `echo()`.

```
$contents = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');
echo( $contents );
```

The above will require that you set config `allow_url_fopen=1` (which is already set by default).

---

If you were to use `include`, instead of the approach I've shown above, there would be one major difference: `include` also *executes* any PHP code it finds inside the fetched document.  In general, this is a really dangerous thing to allow unless you know that you control 100% of the contents of the document being included.

That said: if you *do* want code that works exactly like `include`, you can do something like the following (which is safer because it only fetches a single URL, and it *doesn't* require you to enable `allow_url_include`).

```
$contents = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');
eval('?>'.$contents);
```

If you choose do this, **be certain that you control the full contents of the remote URL**. If someone else controls that file, they will be able to execute arbitrary code on your server.  Don't let that happen.

Comment: i do controls the file i am calling

Comment: i get this error doing this "
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in C:\xampp\htdocs\usersPortal\userportal.php(6) : eval()'d code on line 88"

Comment: @1ftw1: turns out that the trailing `<?php` isn't needed, and actually causes problems. So the eval statement becomes: `eval('?>'.$contents);`. I've updated my answer above.  Let me know if this solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well why you need that, you have control over the code, you can just use one url in while including. Beside using allow_url_include is very dangerous. If you still want to use, you can do it this way.

Make a custom function (A rough code)

```
function url_include($url){
   //now check if $url is the one you want to be included
   if($url=="http://www.mysite.com/file.php"){
     include($url);
   }else{
      //show error or something.
   }
}
```

now use this `url_include("http://www.mysite.com/file.php");` in your page to include url.

Hope this helps

Comment: im trying to keep allow_url_include off to be safe but what to include a file from somewhere else is there a better way of doing this then using include?

Comment: @1ftw1, what if you use `file_get_contents` instead?

Comment: @1ftw1 If you want to be able to dynamically grab its contents: nothing that I know of. If it's only going to be used in a page that is a subfolder, only enable it there by including the .htaccess in that folder, rather than the root.

Comment: @Sabin `file_get_contents` requires the same htaccess permissions.

Comment: As far as i know file_get_contents will not get the php in the file and i get a error "Redirection limit reached". am i of base here?