# Assessing risks of allow_url_include, or alternatives

Tags: php, security

I'm trying to understand the *actual* risks of allow_url_include, or find some practical alternative for this scenario:

Server A has a php-based web page, which fetches data from a number of remote servers (Servers B to J) about their current status. Server A then parses the data returned and displays a summary. The code to get the data and send it back is a PHP script which resides on Servers B to J, and as more servers are added, is becoming a pain to keep up to date - whenever a new feature is required on the summary page, that file must be updated on every server to match what the summary code expects to be sent back.

One obvious solution is to `include` the code to get data, so that the code on Servers B to J looks like:

```
include("http://ServerA/stats/getData.php.source");
echo base64_encode(serialize(getData()));
```

But pretty much every SO question regarding allow_url_include just says "Don't do it". I've struggled to find specific risks associated with this, and how to mitigate them.

The goal here is to have all the code on Server A, so that maintenance / feature additions become much easier to handle. An nfs mount might be practical, but seems a little excessive for a single file. Writing a script on Server A to use ssh to push new code to each server is also a possibility, but would slow down the development cycle.

There are no other developers on Servers B to J, so is allow_url_include really such a risk? What else could it do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the application layer and system layer are **BOTH** secured to an extent that you believe no one can get in - then there is nothing wrong with allowing something like *allow_url_include*

This can be extremely complicated, as you will need a layer on the outside of your application monitoring incoming requests. However it is not impossible!

**Other things to help :**

- [PhpSecInfo](http://phpsec.org/projects/phpsecinfo/)
- [theDevShed](http://thedevshed.co.uk/posts/basic-security-for-apache-and-php-on-centos)

Unless you are **100%** sure you can secure your server to a *more than reasonable* level then I would suggest using an alternative such as **cURL** instead.

Comment: I also found this answer after posting, which has some extra info - basically, if you can completely control the URL which is being fetched, it should be OK http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12274174/allow-url-include-is-there-a-way-to-allow-includes-from-just-one-url. The URL to fetch is a string literal stored on Servers B-J, not dependent on user input. If someone hacks Server A where it is fetched from, I guess I'm screwed anyway :) Given that the end result is code executing on one server which has come from another server, I guess there's little difference in any other solution either.

Comment: When you said an alternative such as cURL, did you mean to fetch the required code? It would still have to be eval()ed wouldn't it? Is that any better than include? In fact, I'm using file_get_contents() and eval() now, to avoid having to set allow_url_include anyway.

Comment: It all depends what your **final** output would be. As you just mentioned you said that code is being executed on another server?? What sort of information are you hoping to get from this?? There are always ways around these sorts of things :)

Comment: Now I'm confused - I thought what I was trying to achieve was clear in the question! Server A is producing the final 'report', but needs data from other servers. This requires some code to execute on those servers and return the data to Server A. I can copy that code by hand onto each of Servers B to J (and counting), but maintenance / updates are painful. And any chance in the 'reporting' code, needs corresponding changes in the 'gathering' code. So, better for each of Servers B-Z to ask Server A for the code each time and always be up to date. That's about it - what's the safest method?

Comment: Have you thought about having each site just running their operations when required? A PHP script that will run gather all the information and output as XML / JSON for you to cURL grab and use as required? That way you could have some sort of authentication mechanism built in?? An extremely simplified API really :)

Comment: That's pretty much what I have now - but the code which gathers the info and generates the XML needs to be updated. On 10 servers and counting. How to make that process ideally zero effort? The thing which _causes_ the change in that code is the 'summariser' on Server A, which needs additional data, for example. So it seems to make sense for _that_ server to hold the latest copy of the gathering data code... I'm happy with file_get_contents() tbh - I was just wondering if there were better ways of distributing PHP code from one server to another.

Comment: Depends where the data is being stored? You could have something similar to what you have now, but have Server A send a query / exec code to the other servers which will accept anything you throw at it. The only downside would be the work you would need to do to secure the entire thing. A simple process, but time consuming